# How to build a recursive table in inline-table-valued function (iTVF)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four parameters to be accepted by the function:

```
@FromDate DATE, @ToDate DATE, @DataInterval INT, @RangeInterval INT
```

The result set is obtained using a CTE:

```
;WITH Dates_CTE (FromDt, ToDt) AS
(

SELECT
DATEADD(D,-@RangeInterval,@FromDate) AS [FromDt],
@FromDate AS [ToDt]

UNION ALL

SELECT
DATEADD(D,@DataInterval,D.FromDt) AS [FromDt],
DATEADD(D,@DataInterval,D.ToDt) AS [ToDt]
FROM Dates_CTE D
WHERE D.ToDt <= @ToDate
)
```

But using a CTE makes it a multi-table-valued function and it becomes a performance-killer.
Is there another way to achieve this in an inline function?

The example of the desired result with the input @FromDate = '20180701', @ToDate = '20180901', @DataInterval = 5, @RangeInterval = 30 is:

```
+------------+------------+
|  FromDate  |   ToDate   |
+------------+------------+
| 2018-06-01 | 2018-07-01 |
| 2018-06-06 | 2018-07-06 |
| 2018-06-11 | 2018-07-11 |
| 2018-06-16 | 2018-07-16 |
| 2018-06-21 | 2018-07-21 |
| 2018-06-26 | 2018-07-26 |
| 2018-07-01 | 2018-07-31 |
| 2018-07-06 | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-11 | 2018-08-10 |
| 2018-07-16 | 2018-08-15 |
| 2018-07-21 | 2018-08-20 |
| 2018-07-26 | 2018-08-25 |
| 2018-07-31 | 2018-08-30 |
| 2018-08-05 | 2018-09-04 |
+------------+------------+
```

How can we achieve this result in an iTVF? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a `tally table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really you need no recursion. Use a table of numbers. Here the table of numbers is generated on the fly it can be persisted in the db for better perfomance.

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATE, @ToDate DATE, @DataInterval INT, @RangeInterval INT;
SELECT @FromDate = '20180701', @ToDate = '20180901', @DataInterval = 5, @RangeInterval = 30;
-- table of 1000 numbers starting 0
with t0(n) as (
 select n 
 from (
    values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
    ) t(n)
),nmbs as(
   select row_number() over(order by t1.n) - 1 n
   from t0 t1, t0 t2, t0 t3
)
select 
  DATEADD(D, @DataInterval*n - @RangeInterval, @FromDate) FromDate
  ,DATEADD(D, @DataInterval*n, @FromDate) ToDate
from nmbs
where DATEADD(D, @DataInterval*n , @FromDate) <= @ToDate;
```

You may need to adjust where conditions per your requierments.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=994a2a97d154703ec1b6081463491c75) with the persisted table of numbers (aka tally table).

Comment: Hello, I am aware of using CTE or While loop but I need to return the table using a iTVF as it is called multiple times across many procedures and the parameters are user inputs.

Comment: @WishIWasACoder,  Persist the table of numbers. Then `select 
  DATEADD(D, @DataInterval*n - @RangeInterval, @FromDate) FromDate
  ,DATEADD(D, @DataInterval*n, @FromDate) ToDate
from nmbs..` is quite suitable for iTVF.

Comment: Are you suggesting creating a table in the database?

Comment: @WishIWasACoder, Yes, exactly. See demo in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tally table inside your inline table-value function.

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers (N INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO Numbers
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 N
  FROM
  (
      VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL)
  ) T1(V) CROSS JOIN
  (
    VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL)
  ) T2(VV) CROSS JOIN
  (
    VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL) --Add Values as needed
  ) T3(VVV);
```

Then create your function as

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc
(
  @FromDate DATE,
  @ToDate DATE,
  @DataInterval INT,
  @RangeInterval INT
)
RETURNS TABLE

  RETURN
  SELECT DATEADD(Day, (@DataInterval * N) - @RangeInterval, @FromDate) FromDate,
         DATEADD(Day, @DataInterval * N, @FromDate) ToDate
  FROM Numbers
  WHERE DATEADD(Day, @DataInterval * N, @FromDate) <= @ToDate;
```

And finally, use it as

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyFunc ('20180701', '20180901', 5, 30);
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab6f0350917a8e6d5ed0b2a0d7cc2ccb)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

you can use while :

```
declare @FromDate DATE = '20180701', @ToDate DATE= '20180901', @DataInterval INT= 5, @RangeInterval INT= 30,@date date ,@r int =0
declare @table table (d1 date, d2 date)

set @date= @FromDate
while (@date <@ToDate )
begin

insert into @table
select dateadd(d,@r,@FromDate ),DATEADD(D,-@RangeInterval+@r,@FromDate)

set @r=@r+@DataInterval
set @date = dateadd(d,@r,@FromDate )
end 

select * from @table
```

Comment: Hello, I am aware of using CTE or While loop but I need to return the table using a iTVF as it is called multiple times across many procedures and the parameters are user inputs